# How to find a specific Element in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a referenced UserControl and want to find a specific child element in C#.
This is my UserControl:

```
<UserControl .. >
     <Viewbox>
         <TextBlock>Text</Textblock>
         <TextBlock>Text</Textblock>
         <TextBlock>Text</Textblock>
     </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

And in my C# project I've got this:

```
UserControl userControl = new UserControl();
```

My question is: How can I find every element TextBlock without knowing the exact tree structure?

---

EDIT:

Just solved it myself.

```
Visual visual = (Visual)userControl.Content;
for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
{
    DependencyObject obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it myself. Here's a snippet if someone comes across the same problem:

```
Visual visual = (Visual)userControl.Content;
for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
{
    DependencyObject obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
}
```